# Python sklearn class_weight passing balanced weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm building a random forest model from sklearn and I usually use class_weight="balanced" in my parameters (let's call this model_1).

```
params={'class_weight': 'balanced',
 'max_depth': 10,
 'max_features': 'auto',
 'min_samples_leaf': 0.25,
 'min_samples_split': 0.25,
 'n_estimators': 50,
 'n_jobs': 6,
 'oob_score': True,
 'random_state': 21,
 'verbose': 1}

model_1 confusion matrix:
            -1    0    1  trueTotal
-1          86   67   59        212
0           31   43   32        106
1           74   80   61        215
predTotal  191  190  152        533
```

I noticed that when I pass in a dictionary calculated from sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight using "balanced" my confusion matrix doesn't match model_1's

```
 from sklearn.utils import class_weight
 keys = np.unique(tdf[targetName])
 values = class_weight.compute_class_weight("balanced", keys,     tdf[targetName].values)
 cw = dict(zip(keys, values))
 cw
 {-1: 0.86371284352215372, 0: 1.5802975885069266, 1: 0.82684563758389262}

 params1 = params.copy()
 params1["class_weight"] = cw
 model_2 confusion matrix
        -1  0  1  trueTotal
 -1         212  0  0        212
 0          106  0  0        106
 1          215  0  0        215
 predTotal  533  0  0        533
```

I'm really just looking for an example on how I can change the class_weight to try and improve my true predictions for -1 and 1 and penalize false positives for -1 and 1 (0 predictions or 0 actuals for predictions of 1 and -1 are ok) given the following cost matrix.  Adjusting the weights aren't producing the predictions that I thought they would so now I'm wondering if my understanding of class_weight is correct.

```
   cost matrix
        -1  0    1 
 -1     10  0  -10       
  0      0  0    0        
  1    -10  0   10
```

** EDIT **

To clarify, class_weight.compute_class_weight("balanced"...) results in the same values as the n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))

```
y = np.where(tdf[targetName] == -1, 2, tdf[targetName])
len(y)/(3*np.bincount(y))
array([ 1.58029759,  0.82684564,  0.86371284])
```

When passed into the model the confusion matrix is not the same as "balanced".

Comment: As per documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html): If ‘balanced’, class weights will be given by n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)). If a dictionary is given, keys are classes and values are corresponding class weights. If None is given, the class weights will be uniform.

Comment: Understood.  But n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)) results in the same values as class_weight.compute_class_weight

Comment: I don't get your point, have you read the documentation that I've linked? What is the desired output that you expect from "balanced"?